# How to find the second highest salary grouped by the business in r

Tags: r

what i want is the output should contain for each business the second highest salary entry only....
for example:

```
customer_id    name            sales firstname lastname  income   business
6            Priyank Dwivedi     2   Priyank  Dwivedi    650000     PES
4              Monika Maurya     3    Monika   Maurya    200000     ITS
1               Rahul Ranjan     3     Rahul   Ranjan    1000000    PES
7               Ambreen Khan     1   Ambreen     Khan    800000     PES
3                     P Paul     3         P     Paul    500000     ITS
5               Sunny Tiwari     2     Sunny   Tiwari    900000     Analytics
2             Mayank Agarwal     3    Mayank  Agarwal    300000     PES
8             Shashank Rawat     1  Shashank    Rawat    100000     Analytics
```

What I want as output is:

```
customer_id    name            sales firstname lastname  income   business
4              Monika Maurya     3    Monika   Maurya    200000     ITS
8             Shashank Rawat     1  Shashank    Rawat    100000     Analytics
7               Ambreen Khan     1   Ambreen     Khan    800000     PES
```

that is second highest salary from each business.

Comment: could you provide a reproducible example your dataframe. `dput(df)` helps you to get the output, so you could post it here. W.r.t. your question I'd suggest to look into something like: sort(x,partial=1)[1] and maybe combine that with `ddply` from the `reshape2` package.

Comment: In combination with what @MattBannert said, what have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

... one solution might be:

```
res <- t(sapply(unique(data[, "business"]),
                function(x, data){
                  # this are the subsets
                  d <- data[x==data[, "business"], ]
                  # order it and take second
                  d[order(d[, "income"], decreasing=TRUE)[2], ] 
                }, data=data))
res
```

with `data` as your data

Comment: Can you explain your answer??

Comment: sure, `unique(data[, "business"])` takes the each unique business, each element than becomes x, eg. the first x="PES". Indexing like `data[x==data[, "business"], ]` gives you an other matrix only with elements where the condition above is TRUE, so eg. all business ="PES". This should be the subset you need. Within this subset you order according to income `d[order(d[, "income"], decreasing=TRUE)[2], ]` and than take the second highest, therefore the [2]

Comment: The problem with your answer is, in the name column instead of showing the correct names it is displaying factor,1

Comment: had the same problem when i tried your example, I than used `as.character()` for all character columns

Comment: before the `sapply`, something like `data[, "name"]<-as.character(data[, "name"])`, probably it is also necessary for the other character columns